# How do I efficiently add the values of inputs that may or may not be visible on page init?

Tags: jquery, input, addition

I'm pretty new to JS and jQuery, so this may be a noob question. I'm building a WordPress theme and the options page lets the user choose how many footer widget slots they want, we'll call that X and the possible values for X are 1-6. If X=4, then I display 4 inputs where they can then specify the widths of each slot.

I also show a running total of all slots so that the user always knows if they're at 100%. My routine to do that is simple, but probably not efficient. I know I could probably do this with a loop, but for now I only understand how to add the literal inputs: input_1 + input_2 + input_3 etc.

This works fine onChange and with keuyup events but the problem is that on page load, my routine does not know how many inputs are visible and if all 6 aren't there, it's not adding the value correctly. I need to alter this routine so that it assumes a value of 0 if the input isn't used, i.e. if X=4 then input_5 and input_6 are hidden.

```
function displaytotal() {
    var num = 0;
    num = parseFloat($('#wa1').val(),10) + 
        parseFloat($('#wa2').val(),10) + 
        parseFloat($('#wa3').val(),10) + 
        parseFloat($('#wa4').val(),10) + 
        parseFloat($('#wa5').val(),10) + 
        parseFloat($('#wa6').val(),10);
    num = Math.round(num);
    if( isNaN(num) ) {
        $('#total100').val('???');
    } else {
        $('#total100').val(num);
        if( $('#total100').val() == 100 ) {
            $('#total100').css({"color":"green"});
        } else {
            $('#total100').css({"color":"red"});
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When elements repeat, it's an indicator to use a class name, not an ID. This way any element with the matching class selector can be used in a loop, regardless of how many there are.

`.filter(":visible")` will select only those that are visible.

```
var num = 0
$('.myClass').filter(":visible").each(function() {
    num = num +  parseFloat($(this).val(),10)        
})
```

Comment: Ah! Duh... I get it. I had figured that out for the showing and hiding of the fields, but didn't understand the (this).val() trick yet. Thanks.

The other issue is that my displaytotal() function appears to be running before the page is fully loaded and that's why the values are missing, hence NaN. I think I need to load the script in the footer, not the head.

Comment: And thanks for the .filter tip too... that's better than what I did...

`var num = 0;
wanum = $('#f_w_wa_num_opt').val();
$('.wa' + wanum + ' input').each(function() {
 num = num + parseFloat($(this).val(),10);
});`